# When is SynchronizationContext.Send called and should my customized SynchronizedContext override it?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I understand the purpose of SynchronizationContext and the appropriate time to use it. But one thing I'm still confused about is SynchronizationContext.Send.

I don't understand why there is SynchronizationContext.Send when it seems the Post is already enough. I understand that the Send is for synchronous call. But under what circumstances is the Send() being useful?

And one related question: when I'm developing my customized SynchronizationContext, when should I override the Send()? Do I have to?

Comment: `Send` dispatches an asynchronous message to the context and **waits for it to complete** as apposed to `Post` which doesn't . Since you are likely not in control of what may call the context implementing it would be wise. Lastly, most developers never have the need to create a custom sync context, they are not the most trivial thing to implement, my spidey senses tells me this is an X/Y problem. What's the use case here?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelRandall, the use case is that I need to ensure every await continuation gets dispatched back to my special thread pool which has some special instrumentation necessary in my particular kind of service. Regarding Send(), I understand the "wait for completion" part, I just don't know what concrete scenario would warrant the existence of this method. Another thing is if I can "not override" it and leave it to default (base) implementation (which simply calls the callback on current thread)

Comment: One more thing to add is that, I tried implementing Send, but it was never called in my test cases. I don't know how to trigger the calling of Send() with test code. Also, I see people implementing Send() with throw NotSupportedException(), now I don't know if that will cause problems down the road or if it's an expected behavior by .net framework, i.e. if the framework sees Send() throwing NotSupportedException it would fallback to call Post() (sounds unlikely though, since it would be a big perf hit)

Comment: A 'concrete' use case for `Send` would be when the method provides a result that you need. Many implementations of `Send` that I have seen, will execute the delegate directly rather than queue & wait if it determines that the method would/could be executed by the current thread. Most implementations that throw in `Send` probably do so because tasks don't use it and they don't care about anything else (SynchronizationContext predates Task, by a large margin).

Comment: I think the design of the SynchronizationContext was really just a thin abstraction over the Send/Post of window messages.